# Jackson JSON/XML provider for Apache wink

Tags: xml, json, apache, rest, jackson

Does Jackson provide Apache wink JSON/XML providers? In our REST project(implemented in Apache Wink), we would like to use Jackson providers for handling JSON and XML content type. Just wanted to know whether libraries already exist or we need to implement our own custom providers. Could you please point me to those libraries(if available)?

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers

Comment: thanks @peeskillet. Does this work with Apache Wink (docs talk abt Jersey & RESTEasy)? But I assume it would work as all are JAX-RS impl. Do we need to register this provider or does it auto-discovered (once added to classpath). Could you let me know whether these provided accept Jackson(or JAXB) annotated POJOs or any special types? I couldn't find related info.

Comment: I don't use Wink, but from the experience I've had with Jersey and Resteasy, when classpath scanning is enabled (e.g. an empty `Application` subclass - there are other means), this provider will be picked up; other wise I need to register the provider. So depends on your configuration

Comment: ok. Will try that out. And a couple Jackson specific queries.. (1) Does these Jackson providers accept Jackson annotated POJOs. Just wanted to know how providers are resolved. (2) To enable JSON/XML content type transformation for a POJO, is it possible to give just one type of annotation, or separate annotations are required?

Comment: I've never really used Jackson for XML mapping. But yes JSON annotation mapping is supported. Annotations are not required is your classes don't need any special serialization/deserialization. Any special universal serialization/deserialization features you want to add could be configured in a `ObjectMapper` itself in a jax-rs `ContextResolver`